# if-elseif-else throwing errors

Tags: errors, algorithm2e

I am trying to create a `if elseif else` algorithm but not its throwing me errors.

The errors say: `!Argument of \algosec@Elseselfstrip has an extra }.<inserted text>` but  cant see that I have inserted an extra `}` anywhere

Packages:

```
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
```

Latex code:

```
 \begin{algorithm}[H]
     \While{true:}
     {
        pl = Poll() \\
        sd = PollSd() \\
        \eIf{time}{
            ok;
        }     
        \ElseIf{response}{
        ok
        }{
        instructions1\;
        instructions2\;
       }

     }
     \caption{Value}
    \end{algorithm}
```

Comment: Have you ever heard of a MWE, i.e. a full document with `\documentclass{...}, `\begin{document}...\end{document}` and the relevant packages? Fragments as this post are not really useful!

Answer (score 1):

You are using an elsed if hence the name `\eIf` already. So it expects an else statement

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
 \begin{algorithm}[H]
     \While{true:}
     {
        pl = Poll() \\
        sd = PollSd() \\
        \eIf{time}{
            ok;
        }   %<----- Here it expects an else block, basically anything
        \ElseIf{response}{
        ok
        }{
        instructions1\;
        instructions2\;
       }
     }
     \caption{Value}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

You can use different macros for example `\uIf` etc. to make it a singleton if followed by `\ElseIf`

Comment: It only shows `if-else`not `if else-if else`.

Comment: @user3580316 That's what I meant with the last sentence. Check the manual it has lots of if else examples.

Comment: Can you please show me an example, I am new to latex and having a alot of issues. I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
 \SetAlgoLined
 \LinesNumbered
 \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
 \Input{Input}
 \Output{Output}
  
        \uIf{this first condition is true}{
        we do that\;
        }
        \uElseIf{this other condition is true}{
        this is done\tcc*[r]{else if}
        }
        \Else{
        in other case, we do this\tcc*[r]{else}
        }

 \caption{Algorithm}
\end{algorithm}
```